# How can I use ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4) server to push routes to clients?

Tags: routing, dhcp, route, isc-dhcpd

**QUESTION:**

I have an infrastructure with 5 servers (Server #1, #2, #3, #4 and #5). I am trying to use a server (Server #5) with ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4) ( https://kea.isc.org/wiki ) to push routes to other servers (Server #1, #2, #3 and #4). The goal is that all servers can communicate with others (`ping`, `ssh`, etc) using a LAN between Servers #2 and 3# (a VPN tunnel).

---

**SERVERS:**

```
Server #1 - DHCPv4 Client;
Server #2 - DHCPv4 Client and OpenVPN Server;
Server #3 - DHCPv4 Client and OpenVPN Client;
Server #4 - DHCPv4 Client;
Server #5 - ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4).
```

---

**SUBNETS:**

```
192.168.56.0/24
10.1.2.0/24
10.1.4.0/24
10.1.6.0/24
10.8.0.1/24 (VPN tunnel)
```

---

**SERVERS SETTINGS:**

NOTE: The infrastructure presented here is part of a test environment that I created on VirtualBox to run the tests (not the real environment). The 192.168.56.0/24 network, for example, is present on all servers.

Information about the LANs (network interfaces) of each server...

**Server #1**

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:56:84:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.6.3/24 brd 10.1.6.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 3514sec preferred_lft 3514sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe56:841f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:12:26:e2:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.3/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s17
       valid_lft 3606sec preferred_lft 3606sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:12ff:fe26:e26c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Server #2**

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:2c:d1:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.6.4/24 brd 10.1.6.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 3856sec preferred_lft 3856sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe2c:d158/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:1c:a6:b9:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.4/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s17
       valid_lft 3897sec preferred_lft 3897sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:1cff:fea6:b959/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ec75:f69e:e65c:1215/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Server #3**

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:71:77:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.4.5/24 brd 10.1.4.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 3741sec preferred_lft 3741sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe71:7707/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:ea:4e:40:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.5/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s17
       valid_lft 3766sec preferred_lft 3766sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:eaff:fe4e:40ae/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.6/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6763:9d85:a754:bf0f/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Server #4**

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e0:d2:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.4.6/24 brd 10.1.4.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 3907sec preferred_lft 3907sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee0:d2c8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:aa:e7:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.6/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic enp0s17
       valid_lft 3907sec preferred_lft 3907sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feaa:e760/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Server #5**

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:63:ce:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.2.2/24 brd 10.1.2.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe63:cec5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:98:ee:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.4.2/24 brd 10.1.4.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s9
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe98:ee35/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b6:6b:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.6.2/24 brd 10.1.6.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s10
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb6:6b50/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: enp0s17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:78:ed:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.2/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s17
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe78:edd4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Thanks!

Comment: And your question is? You describe a scenario, but don't really ask a question here... Also, can you simplify your scenario and narrow it down to the smallest situation that illustrates the problem you're trying to solve? Can you set up what you want using static IPs and routes? (If yes, then DHCP might be the problem... But if no, then maybe you should figure that out first?) You say you want traffic from #1 to #3 to go through #2... But if they all have IPs in 192.168.56.0/24, they'll be able to reach each other directly, no?

Comment: Indeed, the scenario is too complex, and you are not closing it with a question. However, we have been trying to tell you in the last posts asking for consulting/solving complex scenarios is off-topic and not encouraged here. We advise focusing on a small subset of your problems and asking well-defined Unix implementation questions.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger "And your question is?" -> I modified the thread to make it clear (I divided it into 3 parts). "can you simplify your scenario and narrow it down to the smallest situation" -> I have separated the question into three parts to try to meet that.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger "Can you set up what you want using static IPs and routes?" -> There is no special reason for this. If so, we can remove static IPs and routes. "You say you want traffic from #1 to #3 to go through #2... But if they all have IPs in 192.168.56.0/24" -> This is a testing environment. In the real environment these servers will not all be on the 192.168.56.0/24 LAN. Thank you!

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro "Indeed, the scenario is too complex, and you are not closing it with a question.", "We advise focusing on a small subset of your problems and asking well-defined Unix implementation questions." -> I reorganized the thread to suit your suggestions. I can change other things if you find it necessary. Thank you!

Comment: You're still not asking a specific question. If your question is "How Kea (isc) DHCP to push routes to other 3 servers?", then the answer is using the "routers" and "static-routes" attributes. You also don't explain what you tried to do (how did you test it, with ping from server #1 to an IP in server #3?), what you expected, what happened instead and what steps you tried to do to fix it. If your problem is with setting up routes, then DHCP is somewhat out of the picture, make sure you can set up everything statically first, then look into how to push that config with DHCP.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger Please excuse me. I'm trying to improve this thread. This problem is very difficult for me. "You also don't explain what you tried to do (how did you test it, with ping from Server #1 to an IP in server #3?)" -> Yes. The hourly test is a simple ping (ping 10.0.4.4) from Server #1 to Server #3. "what you expected, what happened instead and what steps you tried to do to fix it." -> I would like LAN 10.0.6.5/24 (Server #1) be able to communicate with LAN 10.0.4.0/24 (Server #3) using LAN 10.8.0.0/24 (Server #2).

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger "If your problem is with setting up routes, then DHCP is somewhat out of the picture, make sure you can set up everything statically first, then look into how to push that config with DHCP." -> I already did this and it worked. See here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457347/61742 . I made some corrections. Let me know if there are any other things I can improve. I'm really trying my best. I believe we are close to solving this problem.

Comment: @EduardoLucio so take a look at that answer and try to use it to troubleshoot your current problem... In particular: "You can test that routing works with `ip route get a.b.c.d` on server #1 and server #3." That should tell you what is wrong. You can also look at `ip route` output to dump the whole route table. Your question here is still not specific enough. Try to find out what the root problem is and then ask e.g. "How can I push a static route using Kea DHCP?" and include what `ip route` currently is and what you would like it to be... That way you might get more of a chance of an answer.

Comment: DHCP is actually for giving IP addresses and not routes. You either have static routes, with should be easier for starting and gaining knowledge, and only in more complex scenarios you then go for dynamic routing, which is another can of worms.

Comment: @EduardoLucio isc dhcp or dnsmasq (in your own previous Q/A!) define and/or use option 121 (and/or 249). what makes you think you don't have to for kea? https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/kea-users/2016-October/000559.html . Else I completely agree with everybody that this question is uselessly too complex, long etc.

Comment: @A.B In my tests the isc KEA DHCP is giving IP addresses in the infrastructure presented (I need to do this for the other interfaces individually), done this I will do the isc KEA DHCP push routes. I only ask for a little patience from you. As soon as I finish I'll post the answer here. I could not find anything on the internet that has a direct and enlightening approach to my problem - in my assessment - so I believe that an answer about it can be very useful for people who, like me, have a greater difficulty. Thanks for your help! =D

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Your positioning is very correct. If I really can not solve this problem, I'll follow your suggestion, but I think I'm close to an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoLucio What about the [**LINK**](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/kea-users/2016-October/000559.html) I presented you that tells how to push static routes with KEA using dhcp option 121? Did you read the link?

Comment: @A.B Extremely useful to my question! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About this answer (tutorial):**

This tutorial is intended to demonstrate a "success case" for the ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4) configuration and deploy. Particularly demonstrate the push of routes to DHCP clients. Other points are also considered for the specific case and are there to make the demonstration more didactic.

In the specific case (simulation using VirtualBox) we use an OpenVPN tunnel and we demonstrate how to do a routing to use it in two ways in a LAN-TO-LAN infrastructure.

This tutorial was constructed considering a scenario where we have a server on the Internet (Serverloft) running a Hypervisor (Xen) at one end of the VPN and a corporate LAN at the other end of the VPN where all the servers of both networks are able to communicate in a transparent way.

Other considerations are made throughout this tutorial and we recommend that you read it fully.

We feel the need to do this tutorial since nothing "practical" like it can be found on the internet. This tutorial also targets an audience that like us has greater difficulty with the basic concepts presented here.

Before we continue we would like to thanks the many people who helped in this process. In particular we thank the users: @Filipe Brandenburger , @Rui F Ribeiro , @A.B , @Isaac, @slm and others (unfortunately we can not quote everyone).

**Servers in this tutorial:**

```
Server #1 - DHCPv4 Client (ips ending with 3);
Server #2 - DHCPv4 Client and OpenVPN Server (ips ending with 4);
Server #3 - DHCPv4 Client and OpenVPN Client (ips ending with 5);
Server #4 - DHCPv4 Client (ips ending with 6);
Server #5 - ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4) Server (ips ending with 2).
```

NOTE: All servers are CentOS 7.

**Subnets:**

```
192.168.56.0/24
10.1.2.0/24
10.1.4.0/24
10.1.6.0/24
10.8.0.1/24 (VPN tunnel)
```

**Server #5 - ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4) Server:**

. Installing ISC KEA DHCP (DHCPv4) on CentOS 7

```
yum -y install gcc-c++ openssl-devel wget

cd /usr/local/src/
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/boost_1_67_0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf boost_1_67_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_67_0
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 install
rm -rf /usr/local/src/boost_1_67_0*

cd /usr/local/src/
wget https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/releases/download/REL_2_0_1/log4cplus-2.0.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf log4cplus-2.0.1.tar.gz
cd log4cplus-2.0.1
./configure
make
make install
rm -rf /usr/local/src/log4cplus-2.0.1*

cd /usr/local/src/
wget https://ftp.isc.org/isc/kea/1.4.0/kea-1.4.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf kea-1.4.0.tar.gz
cd kea-1.4.0
./configure --enable-shell
make
make install
rm -rf /usr/local/src/kea-1.4.0*
```

. Create settings (startup settings) for KEA services in systemd (systemctl)...

vi '/usr/lib/systemd/system/kea-dhcp4.service'

```
[Unit]
Description=Kea DHCPv4 Server
Documentation=man:kea-dhcp4(8)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
After=time-sync.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/kea-dhcp4 -c /usr/local/etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

vi '/usr/lib/systemd/system/kea-dhcp6.service'

```
[Unit]
Description=Kea DHCPv6 Server
Documentation=man:kea-dhcp6(8)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
After=time-sync.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/kea-dhcp6 -c /usr/local/etc/kea/kea-dhcp6.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

vi '/usr/lib/systemd/system/kea-dhcp-ddns.service'

```
[Unit]
Description=Kea DHCP-DDNS Server
Documentation=man:kea-dhcp-ddns(8)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
After=time-sync.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/kea-dhcp-ddns -c /usr/local/etc/kea/kea-dhcp-ddns.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

. Create (adjust) the configuration file "/usr/local/etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf"...

```
cp '/usr/local/etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf' '/usr/local/etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf_BAK'
```

vi '/usr/local/etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf'

```
{
    "Dhcp4": {
        "interfaces-config": {
            "interfaces": ["enp0s8", "enp0s9", "enp0s10", "enp0s17"]
        },
        "control-socket": {
            "socket-type": "unix",
            "socket-name": "/tmp/kea-dhcp4-ctrl.sock"
        },
        "lease-database": {
            "type": "memfile",
            "lfc-interval": 1800
        },
        "expired-leases-processing": {
            "reclaim-timer-wait-time": 10,
            "flush-reclaimed-timer-wait-time": 25,
            "hold-reclaimed-time": 3600,
            "max-reclaim-leases": 100,
            "max-reclaim-time": 250,
            "unwarned-reclaim-cycles": 5
        },
        "valid-lifetime": 4000,
        "renew-timer": 1000,
        "rebind-timer": 2000,

        // Defines the "rfc3442-classless-static-routes" option.
        // More details https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460147/61742 .
        "option-def": [{
                "name": "rfc3442-classless-static-routes",
                "code": 121,
                "space": "dhcp4",
                "type": "record",
                "array": true,
                "record-types": "uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8"
            }
        ],

        "subnet4": [{
                "interface": "enp0s8",
                "subnet": "10.1.2.0/24",
                "pools": [{
                        "pool": "10.1.2.3 - 10.1.2.254"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "interface": "enp0s9",
                "subnet": "10.1.4.0/24",
                "pools": [{
                        "pool": "10.1.4.3 - 10.1.4.254"
                    }
                ],

                // Reserve ips for the interfaces that have these MAC ADDRESS on that network.
                "reservations": [{
                        // Server 3# (4)
                        "hw-address": "08:00:27:71:77:07",
                        "ip-address": "10.1.4.5"
                    }, {
                        // Server 4# (6)
                        "hw-address": "08:00:27:e0:d2:c8",
                        "ip-address": "10.1.4.6"
                    }
                ],

                // Defines a route to be pushed to this subnet.
                // More details https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460147/61742 .
                "option-data": [{
                        "name": "rfc3442-classless-static-routes",
                        "data": "24,10,1,6,10,1,4,5"
                    }
                ]

            }, {
                "interface": "enp0s10",
                "subnet": "10.1.6.0/24",
                "pools": [{
                        "pool": "10.1.6.3 - 10.1.6.254"
                    }
                ],

                // Reserve ips for the interfaces that have these MAC ADDRESS on that network.
                "reservations": [{
                        // Server 1# (3)
                        "hw-address": "08:00:27:56:84:1f",
                        "ip-address": "10.1.6.3"
                    }, {
                        // Server 2# (4)
                        "hw-address": "08:00:27:2c:d1:58",
                        "ip-address": "10.1.6.4"
                    }
                ],

                // Defines a route to be pushed to this subnet.
                // More details https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460147/61742 .
                "option-data": [{
                        // Server 3# (4) e Server 4# (6)
                        "name": "rfc3442-classless-static-routes",
                        "data": "24,10,1,4,10,1,6,4"
                    }
                ]

            }, {
                "interface": "enp0s17",
                "subnet": "192.168.56.0/24",
                "pools": [{
                        "pool": "192.168.56.3 - 192.168.56.254"
                    }
                ],
                "option-data": [{
                        "name": "domain-name-servers",
                        "data": "192.168.56.1"
                    }, {
                        "name": "routers",
                        "data": "192.168.56.1"
                    }
                ],

                // Reserve ips for the interfaces that have these MAC ADDRESS on that network.
                "reservations": [{
                        // Server 1# (3)
                        "hw-address": "08:00:12:26:e2:6c",
                        "ip-address": "192.168.56.3"
                    }, {
                        // Server 2# (4)
                        "hw-address": "08:00:1c:a6:b9:59",
                        "ip-address": "192.168.56.4"
                    }, {
                        // Server 3# (5)
                        "hw-address": "08:00:ea:4e:40:ae",
                        "ip-address": "192.168.56.5"
                    }, {
                        // Server 4# (6)
                        "hw-address": "08:00:27:aa:e7:60",
                        "ip-address": "192.168.56.6"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "Logging": {
        "loggers": [{
                "name": "kea-dhcp4",
                "output_options": [{
                        "output": "/usr/local/var/log/kea-dhcp4.log"
                    }
                ],
                "severity": "INFO",
                "debuglevel": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

. Configure network interfaces

These network interfaces will provide the DHCP server for all machines (see "kea-dhcp4.conf" above).

NOTE: In a REAL WORLD SCENARIO the machines that are on the "OpenVPN server side network" would own a DHCP server and machines that are on the "OpenVPN client side network" would own another DHCP server. This division works perfectly as we are talking about the "layer 2" of the OSI model, which is therefore isolated from "layer 3" where there will be "routing", "ip forward" etc, which will be part of the integration between the two networks.

vi '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s17'

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=enp0s17
DNS1=192.168.56.1
GATEWAY=192.168.56.1
IPADDR=192.168.56.2
IPV6INIT=NO
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=NO
```

vi '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8'

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=enp0s8
IPADDR=10.1.2.2
IPV6INIT=NO
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=NO
```

vi '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s9'

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=enp0s9
IPADDR=10.1.4.2
IPV6INIT=NO
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=NO
```

vi '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s10'

```
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=enp0s10
IPADDR=10.1.6.2
IPV6INIT=NO
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=NO
```

**Server #2 - Client DHCPv4 and OpenVPN Server:**

. OpenVPN server settings

vi '/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf'

IMPORTANT: We are only considering the CONFIGURATIONS STRICTLY NECESSARY FOR THE OPENVPN OPERATION IN THE PROPOSED INFRASTRUCTURE ("server.conf" and "client0"). Other settings are required. For more information, check out the OpenVPN documentation. More details on the needs addressed here at this link https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope .

```
dev tun
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.1.6.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.1.4.0 255.255.255.0"
client-to-client
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
```

. OpenVPN client settings

NOTE: These settings are consumed by the client on the server side.

vi '/etc/openvpn/ccd/client0'

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.6 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.1.4.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.1.4.0 255.255.255.0
```

**Server #3 - Client DHCPv4 and OpenVPN Client**

. OpenVPN client settings

vi '/etc/openvpn/client/client0.conf'

```
dev tun
remote 192.168.56.4 1194
```

**Server #2 e #3:**

. Open the firewall for "OpenVPN" (Server #2 and #3)

NOTE: Openvpn is not the focus of the thread so we will not go into details here!

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service openvpn
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload
```

. Enable "ip_forward" (Server #2 and #3)

```
echo -n "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

" >> /etc/sysctl.d/ip_forward.conf
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**Server #1, #2, #3 e #4:**

. Configure network interfaces

vi '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8'

NOTE: All interfaces in all machines follow this same model since the network configurations will be provided by Server #5 (KEA DHCP Server).

```
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEVICE=enp0s8
IPV6INIT=NO
ONBOOT=yes
ZONE=public
```

vi '/etc/sysconfig/network'

```
NETWORKING=yes
```

**Test:**

. This tutorial will have been successfully executed if all of these tests are positive:

```
Server #1
    ping 10.1.4.5 # (#3)
    ssh <USER>@10.1.4.5 # (#3)
    ping 10.1.4.6 # (#4)
    ssh <USER>10.1.4.6 # (#4)
Server #2
    ping 10.1.4.5 # (#3)
    ssh <USER>10.1.4.5 # (#3)
    ping 10.1.4.6 # (#4)
    ssh <USER>10.1.4.6 # (#4)
Server #3
    ping 10.1.6.3 # (#1)
    ssh <USER>10.1.6.3 # (#1)
    ping 10.1.6.4 # (#2)
    ssh <USER>10.1.6.4 # (#2)
Server #4
    ping 10.1.6.3 # (#1)
    ssh <USER>10.1.6.3 # (#1)
    ping 10.1.6.4 # (#2)
    ssh <USER>10.1.6.4 # (#2)
```

---

**Tips:**

Internet (WAN) test

```
curl http://www.google.com
```

Renew DHCP on clients

```
dhclient -r
```

Remove DHCP leases settings from clients:

NOTE: Important to test the operation of the DHCP server.

```
rm -rf $(find /var/lib/NetworkManager/ -name "*.lease" | egrep <NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME>)
```

Remove DHCP leases settings from server:

NOTE: Important to test the operation of the DHCP server.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/kea/kea-leases4.csv*
```

---

**Other guidelines:**

General guidelines and about the environment used for this tutorial:

1. This configuration tutorial was built in a test environment using VirtualBox;
2. All networks in use are "Host-only" and one of them (192.168.56.0/24) has internet (see 3). None of them should have VirtualBox DHCP enabled;
3. By default "Host-only" networks have no internet access ( https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes ). However, in this tutorial https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manjaro-and-virtualbox-host-only-with-internet/28722/12 I teach how to "circumvent" this limitation;
4. The internet (WAN) for the 192.168.56.0/24 network must be activated only when it is necessary. Must be disabled for running tests except to check internet access (`curl http://www.google.com`) on Servers #1, #2, #3 and #4 (see 3);
5. Services such as "dnsmasq" and "iptables" should be disabled on the host when the network tests are executed (ping, ssh, etc) (see 3);
6. Generally speaking, no DHCP should be present on layer 2 of the networks during the tests except what is on Server #5.

---

**Use tun or tap (OpenVPN) - A Discussion:**

We transpose below part of a chat ( chat.stackexchange.com ) between @Eduardo Lucio and @Isaac about the deploy model in this answer. We ( @Eduardo Lucio ) opted, at the moment, for using "tun", even though it was a "more laborious" configuration. However if you want a truly transparent integration between the networks on both sides of the VPN opt for tap (with all its pros and cons). I believe that the clarifications of @Isaac are very relevant to decide what to use (tap or tun) and so are transposed here so that it can reach more people.

> Eduardo Lucio Sat 15:22 @Isaac
>   https://serverfault.com/questions/21157/should-i-use-tap-or-tun-for-openvpn/21168#21168
>   I believe this is the way to get things done without a router. Look:
>   "if you need to bridge two ethernet segments in two different
>   locations - then use tap. in such setup you can have computers in the
>   same ip subnet (eg 10.0.0.0/24) on both ends of vpn". So "vpn will act
>   like ethernet switch". But there comes another question ... With this
>   model I could have, for example, machines that are in the network
>   10.7.1.0/24 (VPN side A) communicating transparently with the network 192.168.58.0/24 (VPN side B)?
>
> Isaac Sat 22:19 You are starting to make the right questions.
>
> But you do have a router on each network!! Well, kind of.
>
> There are only two ways in which a packet will reach a computer: (1)
>   The computer is part of the same **wire** as another computer (the
>   same layer 2 scope) like all ports of a (simple) switch (or the old
>   name of hub) or belong to the same VLAN (if you do not have experience
>   with VLANs please just keep this data point for future reference and
>   forget I ever mentioned it for now).
>
> Isaac Sat 22:52 (2) The packet gets **routed** between two layer 2
>   scopes by a router. The decision of whether to route a packet (or not)
>   is taken by following the route table of the switch.
>
> Up to this point that is just a general network description that you
>   might find irrelevant to your specific use case until you also realize
>   that when you tell a computer to **forward** packets that computer is
>   acting as a routing device, in short, a router. That router needs to
>   have routing tables. For example, Assuming ( you really have a mess of
>   numbers on every question they are different, it makes quite difficult
>   to being specific) the server 4 (at 10.1.4.6) which is the VPN client
>   should have forward activated and must be set to route all packets it
>   see that have 10.1.6.x as destination to the tun interface. The
>   packets will enter the VPN, and exit the VPN on the other side. Server
>   3 (on the same network range 10.1.4.y at 10.1.4.5) just need to have a
>   default (gateway) route to send all packets that are **not** in its
>   own network range (10.1.4.0/24) to the GW of 10.1.4.6.
>
> Once the packets from the VPN reach the other computer server2 (at
>   10.1.6.4) they must be **routed** as well to the **router** at the office and the router at the office must have a route entry to send
>   any packet with destination 10.1.4.x to server 2. Server 2 must
>   internally route (and have such route entry) all packets it receive to
>   the tun interface. Is it clearly explained? All of that routing is
>   needed because the device used is a tun (a layer 3 device).
>
> A much simpler (and more insecure) device is a tap (a layer 2 device).
>   Think of it as a switch to which you add computers. It will forward
>   all packets it receive, be those directed to any (level 3) IP address
>   or be those broadcast packets, ARP resolutions and others. In such
>   sense, that will open computers on your office LAN to ARP attacks from
>   computers on the other side of the VPN. All the computers on both
>   sides of the VPN will become a large happy (everyone trust every
>   other) family. Having said that, then yes packets that originate on IP
>   address 10.7.1.0/24 will appear at the other side of the VPN. But the
>   way you phrase your question: (machines at 10.7.1.0/24 and
>   192.168.58.0/24 will be able to communicate?) forces a NO answer. The only way in which computers at dissimilar (private) networks could
>   communicate each other is when they have their local addresses
>   translated to the external (remote) addresses via NAT (Network Address
>   Translation) or similar. So each side of the NAT will see the same
>   network range. All the above just covers IPv4. You will need to review
>   it and extend for IPv6.

Comment: There is way to make this infrastructure work without router (routing), more details and some pros and cons here: https://serverfault.com/a/21168/276753 .